# How to handle closing of a previously opened window

Tags: javascript

I have a form where the user fills out stuff. Towards the end they click on a link which opens up a new window to record a video. Once they are done recording they close the window.

How can I react to the closing of the window on the first window form? I may want to submit the form automatically or have an ajax request started to display info etc... If this isn't possible what do you suggest?

Edit:

Parent window:

```
function someAlert() {
 alert("success");  
}
```

Child window:

```
window.onunload =window.opener.someAlert();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you opened it with window.open, you can call

```
window.opener.someJavaScriptFunctionInParent();
```

call it with `window.onunload` or right before `window.close()`

Comment: window.onunload = function(){window.opener.someAlert();}